# How can I visualize similarity scores in a color schemes? (Tensor)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pytorch, similarity

I have a similarity scores in *"sims"* variable and I want to plotting similarity scores in a matrix preferably in color schemes. The more information about the *"sims"* variable is like that:

```
  import tensorflow.compat.v2 as tf

  print(sims) #Tensor("ExpandDims:0", shape=(1, 64, 64, 1), dtype=float32)
  print(sims[0]) #Tensor("strided_slice_6:0", shape=(64, 64, 1), dtype=float32)
  tf.print(sims[0][:], output_stream=sys.stderr)
```

The output of these rows are given the following screen shot.

[image: output]

To visualize the scores in color matrix I try to use plt.matshow method but I cannot convert the Tensor to numpy array (sims[0].numpy()) because it gives an error.

> AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'.

Also I can't use plt.matshow. It gives the following error:

> NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor
> (strided_slice_10:0) to a numpy array. This error may indicate that
> you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported

How can I visualize these scores in a matrix (64x64) like this?

[image: similarity matrix]

Comment: Your first error indicates one of the following a) tensorflow version is lower than 2.0 b) eager execution is disabled so you cannot call tensor.numpy()

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a couple of methods in a simple way by converting `Tensor` array to `Numpy` array and plot image as follows.

**Using PIL:**

```
# sims is a Tensor <tf.Tensor: shape=(64, 64, 1), dtype=float64>

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline  

data = sims.numpy()
img = Image.fromarray(data,'RGB')
img.save('my.png')
img.show()
```

**Using Matplot:**

```
data = sims.numpy()
data.resize(64,64)
plt.figure(figsize = (10,10))
plt.imshow(data, interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```